# How send an array or list of strings in retrofit with same key but different indexes?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an api that accepts multiple values with same key but different index e.g.
phone_no[0]="1234"
phone_no[1]="5678"

I need to send an array or list of strings that contains phone numbers. I have tried using

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_user_by_phone.php")
Call<PojoGetFriendsListResponse> getUserFromPhone(@Field("phone_no") ArrayList<String> phone_no);
```

but it generates request body like below

```
phone_no=%2B1234&phone_no=%2B5678
```

is there any way to generate a requestbody like this?

```
phone_no[0]=%2B1234&phone_no[1]=%2B5678
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
HashMap<String, String> phoneNumbers= new HashMap<>();
 phoneNumbers.put("phone_no[0]", "99912443432");
 phoneNumbers.put("phone_no[1]", "99912443433");
 phoneNumbers.put("phone_no[2]", "99912443434");

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_user_by_phone.php")
Call<PojoGetFriendsListResponse> getUserFromPhone(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: tried this and it works. I created keys based on index as well. Thank you.

Comment: You can thank me by accepting this answer (tick button) :)